# how to define function within an object you make in typescript

Tags: typescript, object

I have written the following object in typescript, which I need for a stub in unit testing (I know the values/function definitions make no sense but it's just a stub):

```
    const obj = {
      isEmpty: true,
      testName: 'unitTest',
      getTime: () => 5,
      success: () => {},
      fail: () => {},
      wait: () => {},
    };
```

`getTime`,`success`,`fail` and `wait` are supposed to be functions, but when I hover over them in VSCode, they are given as properties (like `isEmpty` and `testName`). Is there any way I can make it so they are strictly recognised as functions? (this is important later on in the unit test)

Comment: What do you mean by "given as properties"?  They are properties.  (Of function types.)  Can you elaborate on how this code is being used and in what specific way it doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a type for obj like this. You editor should recognize it as functions now.

```js
type objType = {
  isEmpty: boolean;
  testName: string;
  getTime(): number;
  success(): void;
  fail(): void;
  wait(): void;
};

const obj: objType = {
  isEmpty: true,
  testName: "unitTest",
  getTime: () => 5,
  success: () => {},
  fail: () => {},
  wait: () => {},
};
```

[image: example]

Example in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKwCrmgXigbwLACgpQCWAzgKIC2YoAXFHDDADYQCGAdgNx4HATHAA5FuQi1+AJ0JsA5l3xRpEYEkIiAFAEpabAK7k4EcXILEdAYzN9im2gDcYhACbGoAMxaFGNqPacuA7h7A3r7OeAC+cnhmMGz8sIi08MioUBg48iQUVCC0wOI6EAA03FC8-EIitABEOmyEynzA1SXyisqqolCaaQB8UACsrSbmlsTEtD1o-Zjhw24ejJMafVhzpYENy6uzrZF4eMkAdKYWVpp4QA)

Comment: In VSCode they still appear as properties

Comment: @SaboBoz Excuse me, I used the wrong syntax . I updated my answer to reflect the correct syntax. I also added a screenshot of the code in VSCode and it's correctly displaying 'method' instead of 'property' now.